# Adição em um autocomplete

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Tenho um autocomplete com o código abaixo.

```
<p:outputLabel styleClass="rotulos" value="Fornecedor:" />
        <p:autoComplete id="inputfornecedor" update="msgcontapagar"
            value="#{contapagarBean.object.fornecedor}" effect="fold" completeMethod="#{contapagarBean.completeFornecedor}"
             converter="fornConverter">             
        </p:autoComplete>
```

Estou procurando uma maneira de caso o fornecedor não coincidir com nenhum listado aparecer um button suspenso com a opção de adiciona-lo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode definir no seu controller (ManagedBean) um atributo do tipo Boolean.
Quando você realizar uma busca e os resultados vierem vazio, você seta este atributo como false.

```
private Boolean fornecedorExiste = true;//<--
private String fornecedorSelecionado;

public List<String> completeText(String query) {
    fornecedorExiste = true;
    FornecedorDao dao = new FornecedorDao();
    List<String> results = dao.listar(query);
    if (results.isEmpty()) {
        fornecedorExiste = false;//<--
    }
    return results;
}
```

E vincula este atributo ao rendered do commandButton

```
<p:outputPanel autoUpdate="true">
    <p:commandButton id="btnNovo" value="Novo"
                rendered="#{not testeControl.fornecedorExiste}" />
</p:outputPanel>
```

Desse modo sempre que não houver resultados para retornar (o fornecedor pesquisado não existir) o botão será renderizado.